# Virtual memory clarification - allocation of large contiguous memory

Tags: linux, windows, memory, memory-management

I have an application where I have to allocate on Windows (using operator new) quite a large memory space (hundreds of MB). The application is 32 bit (we don't use 64 bit for now, even on 64 bit systems) and I enabled /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker option to be able to use 4 GB of user space memory.

*Question* If I need to allocate, say 450 MB of contiguous memory does the virtual address space of the process need to have a contiguous large enough space *and* additionally the physical memory does not have to be fragmented on the system ? I ask this because I can make it so that my application reserves a large enough contiguous space but don't know if other applications on the system can affect me in this way. Does OS page tables need to translate contiguous virtual addresses seen by the application into *contiguous* physical addresses ?

Comment: Even `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` doesn't give you the full 4GB.  And it only has an impact if you've changed some system parameters as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze On Windows 7 64 bit(professional) at least it works by default. As long as PE image is marked with large space aware.

Comment: @Ghita On a 64 bit system, when compiling in 64 bit mode, I would hardly imagine a restriction to 2GB, ever.

Comment: @JamesKanze the restriction applies on x86 compiled images, ofcourse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the memory is simply used in your software, then your 450MB allocation will only need a hole of 450MB in the virtual space. It can be satisfied with pages from every corner of the memory system [as long as there is at least 450MB available somewhere in the system - including swapspace].

Your system will get a little bit better performance if the OS is able to allocate the pages in contiguous blocks of 2MB a piece [using "large pages" of 2MB at a time]. But the system will fall back to individual 4KB pages if it needs to.

One of several benefits with a paged memory architecture is that any physical page can be placed at any virtual address. In some systems, for example Xen virutalization manager in Debug mode, pages are INTENTIONALLY allocated out of sequence, to make it easier to detect when the system makes assumptions about memory pages being contiguous.

Comment: +1. I think mentioning swapspace was a key insight to help explain why contiguous physical memory is completely irrelevant. Any given virtual page could be at one physical RAM location when you write to it, and then a few minutes later could be in a different place in RAM, because it has been swapped out and back in during that time. You might not even *have* 450MB of RAM, let alone contiguous, but the virtual memory system still at least has a chance of making your program run :-)

Comment: The OS will check if the required space is available. Some of that requested memory may not be readily available as pages in RAM, and require use of swapping to allow the process to access the memory. However, if there is no free space in swap, and not enough pages available in RAM, then the allocation will fail. So swapspace is part of "do we have enough memory to allocate X MB".

Comment: And of course Linux (mentioned in tags but not in the question) can make things even more exciting when overcommit is enabled. Then the allocation might succeed even if there isn't enough space available, and if there still isn't space when you actually access the memory something (possibly you) will get killed. In that case, swapspace plus an X% margin is part of "do we have enough memory", and "enough" is a bit of a flexible concept.

Comment: Yes. Makes it even more fun when you write system software, and Linux decides to "shotgun" your user-mode system control process... Whilst debugging the cause of "my system stopped working" is quite rapidly turned into "Doh! OOM-killer shot our main process", but then you have to figure out who ate all the pies - I mean all the memory, and why it's doing that. Which typically tends to be broken drivers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys. It's comforting to know that virtual contiguity has nothing to do with physical (be it memory or page file). This makes things a lot easier for the programmer(and system stability) indeed.

Comment: Might want to note that virtual memory fragmentation can happen, making it impossible to get a contiguous 450 MB in virtual addresses. ASLR library randomization is especially bad for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be concerned about contiguity of the physical memory. That's one thing that virtual to physical address translation helps you with. As long as you can reserve a chunk of the address space and back it with physical memory, wherever it happens to be, things are going to work.

Comment: Thanks for prompt replay. I know I can make sure I have enough contiguous memory in process VM but on the other hand I need to make sure that other applications in the system does not affect my ability in allocating that contiguous memory.

Comment: Each process runs in its own virtual address space.

Comment: In other words, if the system allows me to allocate 2 x 200 MB of memory will it allow me to allocate only 1 chunk of 400MB (process VM has space for 400MB) ?

Comment: Yes, it's "virtual". But how does VM contiguity relate for physical contiguity ?

Comment: Those contiguities are unrelated and one does not necessitate the other. Whether or not you can allocate a 400 MB chunk of virtual address space depends on the previous allocation history. The virtual address space can become fragmented.